# No me detecta la librería tweepy y keyboard cuando la importo en el código

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, keyboard

Queria preguntar si alguien sabe como podría arreglar esto, he instalado las dos librerías con **pip install tweepy** y **pip install keyboard** con cmd como cualquier librería pero estas dos no entiendo el porque no funcionan.

```
import tweepy

import keyboard
```

**Mensaje de error tweepy**: No se ha podido resolver la importación "tweepy".

**Mensaje de error keyboard**: La importación "keyboard" no se ha podido resolver desde el origen

Por si la version de Python tiene algo que ver la que tengo es la 3.12

Esta es la ruta de instalación de las librerías: **C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages**

Comment: No uses nunca pip como comando, ejecútalo como modulo, es decir con  `python -m pip install tweepy`, o en windows tambien puedes usar `py version ...`, es decir `py 3.12  -m pip install tweepy`. Si tienes varias instalaciones de Python o usas un entorno virtual asegúrate de invocar el interprete correcto / tener activado el entorno. Si estas perdido agrega esta linea a tu script: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`, la salida es la ruta al interprete que estas usando, a unas malas puedes usar la ruta que te imprime : `ruta_al_interprete -m pip install tweepy`

Comment: a ejecutarlo como modulo te refieres al mismo código? O en el  cmd? Y estoy usando windows y visual studio code

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando instalas con pip en la terminal/cmd, en vez de usar `pip install lo_que_sea`, uses `python -m pip install lo_que_sea` /   `py <version>  -m pip install lo_que_sea `, o la ruta absoluta al interprete seguida de  `-m pip install lo_que_sea`. La clave siempre esta en que el interprete que invoques debe ser el mismo que usas para ejecutar tu proyecto.Luego obviamente mira la salida de pip y asegúrate que no hay excepciones y el modulo se instala correctamente.El 99% de los errores como el tuyo se deben a instalar las librerias en otro interprete/venv instalado en el sistema

Comment: Ya esta arreglado gracias! eso no era, era que estaba programando con python 3.11 y no 3.12 igualmente gracias esa forma de instalar las librerías no la sabia

Comment: Era precisamente eso :), estabas instalando los paquetes en un interprete (3.12) distinto al que usabas para ejecutar el código (3.11). Ese es uno de los problemas de usar pip directamente (aunque no el único)...

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente necesites utilizar otra versión del manejador de paquetes:

```
pip3 install tweepy 
pip3 install keyboard
```

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y no me ha funcionado he reiniciado el ide pero nada